# Capacitance dependence on separation between plates

Tags: experimental-physics, electric-circuits, capacitance, dielectric

I know that the capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor is $C = \frac{\varepsilon S}{d}$. I am supposed to perform a linear regression to obtain $\varepsilon$, however it turns to be a quadratic relation, [image].

My professor told us to justify it, so it might not be a mistake. It cannot be edge effect as the point that behave badly if we consider it a linear relation are those with smaller separation between plates. It cannot be caused by the saturation of the dielectric we used, as the electric field wasn't that strong. The problem isn't the absence of dielectric in a part of the separation between plates either.

We are using a parallel circular plate condensator. The surface of the plates is $S = \pi \left(\frac{0.255}{2}\right)^{2}$ m$^{2}$.

Comment: For a given plate separation you are getting a capacitance which seems to be too low.  How did you keep the plates "pressed" onto the dielectric because with a dielectric of thickness $\frac 12 \,\rm mm$ a small air gap across  parts of the plates will have a large effect.  Also how flat were the plates?

Comment: The capacitance is not that low, the diameter of the plates was $D = 0.255$ m, so without dielectric, at a distance of $0.5$ mm between the plates the capacitance would be around $900$ pF. And the plates were totally flat. The dielectric was well pressed, as it was held just by the capacitor's plates.

Comment: Well pressed by the weight of the top plate might not be good enough?  If you can repeat the experiment distribute some weights on the top plate to see if that has any effect.

Comment: It is not an experimental issue, as similar results have been obtained by other groups and we are supposed to find the reason why the quadratic regression works better and the linear term is a better stimation of $\varepsilon S$ than the slope of the linear regression. It does have a physical meaning, said my proffesor.

Comment: How was the capacitance measured?

Comment: We had a RLC circuit at a constant frequency, the resistance and inductance were constant and the capacitance at which the circuit presented resonance was determined using a variable capacitor and an oscilloscope. Once we determined the capacitance of resonance we connected another capacitor, the one whose capacitance is represented on the plot, in parallel with the previous, for a fixed separation of the plates we can easily determine the capacitance knowing the one of the other capacitor.

Comment: Was the dielectric solid? If so, did you keep putting different thicknesses of dielectric between the plates to fill the gap as you changed the size of this gap?

Comment: It was solid and yes, all the gap was filled with dielectric

Comment: But did you ensure it was filled by using several discs of dielectric of different thickness, to suit the different gap sizes, or was some other method used?

Comment: We used several discs

Comment: I think Philip Wood is asking if you used one disk of dielectric for each measurement of $d$, or did you increase the thickness of dielectric by using several disks of the same thickness?

Comment: 1. How exactly did you *easily determine the capacitance knowing the one of the other capacitor*? 2. How did you measure $d$? 3. What are your raw data values from your measurements?

Comment: Share your data. It wold be helpful for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Since the only variation is the width of the dielectric material, and other effects have been already excluded, it could be a material that has a finite resistance. So there is a parallel resistor involved with a linear decreasing value the smaller the gap becomes reducing the apparent capacitance. This could shift the resonance frequency yielding an (apparently) non-linear dependency.