# A relationship between parallel plate capcatior's capacitance & it's spacing distance

Tags: capacitance

In my experiment class, I measured a curve between the parallel plate capacitor's capacitance and it's spacing distance. But the result is not very similar to expectation - despite the spacing distance is obviously smaller than the capacitor's size, a curve looks like a quadratic.

I find some similar question about this topic, yet the problem cannot be solved. Also, I tried to find some related articles about this, I failed it too. Please help me to fix this problem.

- capacitance is measured by electrostatic pressure between plates.

similar question : [Capacitance dependence on separation between plates](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/366035/capacitance-dependence-on-separation-between-plates)

Comment: Have you evaluated the error in each of your measurements? And the effect on the results?